# Autocomplete Get Selected Elements Id

Tags: java, android, database, autocomplete

I just started with Android, and I have issues with autocomplete selected results.

I have a CutomerDB with these columns:

`c_id`, `m_id`, `c_name`

I have a list with names which is coming from Database "c_name", and passed to adapter. This is working fine.
Now, if user selects the name, I want the the `c_id` and `M_id` of a particular customer.

Note that there are multiple customers with same name, eg:- customer database: `{1,1,test}`, `{2,1,test}`, `{3,1,testing}`

So when I type "t" it gives me this result: test, test, testing in autocomplete, but after selection I need that customers `c_id` and `m_id`.

Comment: you just need to create a `Customer` class, which will contain the name and IDs. And then pass a list of `Customer`s to the adapter. Also you can override `toString` method of your `Customer` to return the name.

Comment: i m started to android can you show me some example how to do it

Comment: @SiddheshNayak you want to get the id of the item selected from dropdown in your autoCompleteTextView() right ?

Comment: can you upload some examples is jsfiddle, or github or somewhere i have just started with android

Comment: i just created customer class with setters & getters and toString return C_Name and converted that class to ArrayList and passed to adapter autocomplete is working fine now how to get id

Comment: now i created another class that extends adapter and it worked ref: "https://akshaymukadam.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/how-to-create-autocompletetextview-using-custom-filter-implementation/"

Answer (score 3):

Implement `OnItemClickListener()` to your `autoCompleteTextView` and you can get the id's easily.

```
  act.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d("ACT", " pos >> " + i);


                selectedId = yourList.get(i).yourId;


    });
```

Comment: {1,1,test} {2,1,test} {3,1,fest}
so if i type "t" and select second test then i = 1
but if if i type "f" and select fest then i = 0

Comment: @SiddheshNayak yes yourlist == the items you are showing in your dropdown. 
and get(i) is the index you just selected.
and yourId is the id or whatever the field you want to get from your list. Be it the id, name, etc

Comment: can you upload some examples is jsfiddle, or github or somewhere i have just started with android

Comment: @SiddheshNayak i am sure you will find plenty of codes/example on the internet :) just google it